# How to select a table on a page with several tables with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to select a specific table (I marked in the image what I want to get) but the page has many tables. How do I select the table I want?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-tipo-de-participante-ptBR.asp'
pagina = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(pagina.content, 'html.parser')

tabelas = soup.findAll('table')
```

[The tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPPS1.jpg)

Comment: You need some kind of unique identifier or something about the structure to let beautifulsoup know which one to pick out. Is is always the 5th one? Does it have any other class/id info? Does it always have that caption/other data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each table as a unique caption as @match said.

This is an complete example that gets only the table you have marked in image.

Caption of table is **IBrX-50**

```py
import urllib.request as request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag
from typing import List


html = BeautifulSoup(
    request.urlopen(
        "http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-tipo-de-participante-ptBR.asp"
    ).read().decode("ISO-8859-1"),
    "html.parser",
)

key = "IBrX-50"
tables: List[Tag] = html("table")
try:
    table = [
        *filter(lambda tbl: tbl.find("caption").text.strip() == key, tables)
    ][0]
    # do whatever when table is found
except IndexError:
    # do whatever when table not found
    pass
```